# Interesting blown-away/blown-away interesting dandelion

Tags: word-order

Which word order is correct for compound hyphenated adjectives?
▪︎ That [interesting blown-away/blown-away interesting] dandelion was intercepted by the cats.

Comment: Wouldn’t a blown-away dandelion be already gone and so impossible to be caught by the cats?

Comment: When you say "blown away", are you actually referring to the seeds which have been separated from the main body of the plant and are now all separate entities from one another in the air?

Comment: You're right, but the question hasn't been answered yet.

Comment: That's because your example is such an odd one. Does 'blown-away dandelion' refer to the flying seeds or the bare stem, and is it interesting before or after being blown on? _Blown-away interesting_ suggests that it was before.

Comment: "Blown-away" isn't a adjective.  "dandelion" doesn't mean what you think it means. There is no special rule for hyphenated adjectives. The question is not well asked, and doesn't have an answer.